# Requiring a version range for a feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, p2

I have the following situation:

- an Eclipse plug-in (A) which contains base functionality, grouped in two features
- an Eclipse plug-in (B) which contains add-on functionality in one feature and builds on the first plug-in

The two plug-ins have independent lifecycles, but periodically plugin (B) is released and its update site contains contains the latest features from (A) and (B).

What I want to enforce is that a certain feature from plugin (B) is only installable with features from plugin (A) of at least a certain version. So for instance when installing (B) 1.1.0 I should be able to enforce that the features from (A) are at least at version (1.3.0).

I've tried/considered the following:

- bump the dependencies in one of manifests from (B). That does not sound right, since the plug-ins work fine together ; this is a distribution issue
- in the feature.xml for (B), include the other features, e.g. `<includes  id="some.feature" version="1.3.0"/>` . This creates a hard requirement on that version, but I want an 'at least' constraint
- in the feature.xml for (B), include the other features with a version range, e.g. `<includes  id="some.feature" version="[1.3.0,)"/>` . This is illegal in feature.xml files

What options do I have to require a feature with a version range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a dependency on another feature to your feature.xml, this can specify a matching rule for that dependency. Here you can say 'version greater or equal'.

Something like:

```xml
<requires>
  <import feature="org.eclipse.e4.rcp" version="1.3.100" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
</requires>
```

This is configured on the 'Dependencies' tab of the feature.xml editor.